# Doing searches with fragments

Tags: android, search, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I'm setting up my app for use with Honeycomb, and want the search results of my app to be placed inside a fragment in the main activity. However, the standard Android search starts up another `Activity` when landscape, when I want the results to instead go into a fragment. What I have to override where? I'm trying to override `onSearchRequested` but I can't see where I can get the query's string from.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android search with Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230893/android-search-with-fragments)